# Trying to update records after the ItemReader in Spring Batch; not getting committed to the Database

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, spring-batch

I have a custom Item reader which reads data another reader which is a JdbcCursorItemReader (Which reads data from the Request table in the database), builds a list of specific size and returns a list of items.

The request table has an id, type and a status.

I want to update the status of the id's that have been read by the reader to something like PROCESSING so my application can display that the request ids are being processing in the batch. Also while processing the items if there is any business exception, I want to update the table for the ids with certain status.

I wanted the status updating part to be in a separate transaction so that if an item is read and is being processed the status for those requests says PROCESSING rather than REQUESTED.

I am using @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NE W) on the method which updates the status of the request.

I am using separate data sources and transaction managers for spring batch tables and my application specific tables.

I am using JDBC template to update the status.

I am using javax.sql.DataSource for my application data source, JpaTransactionManager for my application transaction manager and HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.

The database is Oracle.

When I turn the debug log on, I see that it suspends the main transactions, a new transaction is being used when update status is being called from the reader, it is committed and then resumes the suspended transaction. But I dont see the change on the database. The transaction log says committed but I dont see the changes in the database. Once the batch completes then I see the changes to the request table in the database. Am I missing something?

Here is the log:

`15:40:26 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'updateStatus' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@36dd518b] for JPA transaction
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.s.AbstractTransactionImpl - begin
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.j.JdbcTransaction - initial autocommit status: true
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.j.JdbcTransaction - disabling autocommit
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@3a7b058e]
15:40:48 [main] INFO  c.c.c.f.c.a.b.RequestReader - Reading...
15:40:48 [main] INFO  c.c.c.f.c.a.b.SecuritiesReader - End of Input Data from  request id ItemReader
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [*.updateStatus]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@628b6e47] for JPA transaction
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.s.AbstractTransactionImpl - begin
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.j.JdbcTransaction - initial autocommit status: true
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.j.JdbcTransaction - disabling autocommit
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@88f431d]
15:40:48 [main] INFO  c.c.c.f.c.a.b.s.i.InstrumentIdentifierServiceImpl - Updating the status of Request Id's
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - UPDATE REQUEST SET    STATUS         = ?        , MESSAGE      = ? WHERE  ID    = ?
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@628b6e47]
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.s.AbstractTransactionImpl - committing
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.j.JdbcTransaction - committed JDBC Connection
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.j.JdbcTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@628b6e47] after transaction
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.j.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
15:40:48 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Typically this scenario is handled with a ChunkListener.  The listener's beforeChunk is used to "tag" all of the items to be read, then the listener's afterChunk handles the subsequent update after the items have ben processed. Another approach is to use the StepExecutionListener to tag all of the items to be processed within the step.

With regards to what is occurring, it sounds like you're running into the issue of nested transactions.  Since you have an outer transaction, the inner one won't get applied until the outer one commits.